# retreiving fields from asscoaied models cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I dont understand from the docs why I cant retrieve selected fields from associated data.
 I have 2 many to many relationships in the contain which displays everything fine.

```
$query3 = $this->find()
              ->contain(['Subjects','AvailabilityForStudents'])
              ->select([
                  'Students.id','Students.first_name','Students.last_name','Students.address_billing','Students.address_lat','Students.address_long',
                  'Students.class_year','Students.address_street','Students.address_suburb','Students.address_postcode','Students.address_state'])
               ->where(['Students.id IN' => $stids])
              ->order(['Students.first_name' => 'ASC'])
              ->hydrate(true);
```

My Question is that instead of getting every field from the contained models why cant I select fields from the contained model as below?  I am not selecting based on a criteria like in matching clause?

```
   $query3 = $this->find()
              ->contain(['Subjects','AvailabilityForStudents'])
              ->select(['Subjects.name','Subjects.id','AvailabilityForStudents.id',
                  'Students.id','Students.first_name','Students.last_name','Students.address_billing','Students.address_lat','Students.address_long',
                  'Students.class_year','Students.address_street','Students.address_suburb','Students.address_postcode','Students.address_state'])
               ->where(['Students.id IN' => $stids])
              ->order(['Students.first_name' => 'ASC'])
              ->hydrate(true);
```

//student model

```
 $this->hasMany('AvailabilityForStudents', [
            'className' => 'AvailabilityForStudents',
            'foreignKey' => 'student_id',
            'dependent' => false,
        ]);

  $this->belongsToMany('Subjects', [
            'foreignKey' => 'student_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'subject_id',
            'joinTable' => 'subjects_students'
        ]);

      //update contain
 $query3 = $this->find()
                   ->contain([

                              'Subjects'=>['fields'=>['name','id','SubjectsStudents.student_id']],
                              'AvailabilityForStudents'  ])
              //   ->contain(['Subjects','AvailabilityForStudents'])
                 ->where(['Students.student_unallocated' =>  1,'Students.student_inactive' =>  0])

              ->order(['Students.first_name' => 'ASC'])
              ->hydrate(true);
```

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html

Comment: What is your current model(Is it Students?) and can you post the association you made in the model?

Comment: I added it in above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing right.
You can try this also,

```
 $query3 = $this->find()
                  ->contain([
                                'Subjects'=>['fields'=>['name','id','SubjectsStudents.student_id']],
                              'AvailabilityForStudents'=>['fields'=>'id']
                           ])
                  ->select(['Students.id','Students.first_name','Students.last_name','Students.address_billing','Students.address_lat','Students.address_long',
                      'Students.class_year','Students.address_street','Students.address_suburb','Students.address_postcode','Students.address_state'])
                   ->where(['Students.id IN' => $stids])
                  ->order(['Students.first_name' => 'ASC'])
                  ->hydrate(false)->toArray();
```

Comment: I get the error from the above code 'Subjects is not associated with Subjects '.  I dont get why this doesnt work

Comment: I have requested you this "What is your current model(Is it Students?) and can you post the association you made in the model? –", If you can provide this, then I can give you good resolution to your issue. @jagguy

Comment: Can you share your Team Viewer access, so that I can debug @jagguy

Comment: My Team Viewer doesnt work. I copied your code in exactly and fixed a missing quote. Must sbe omething different with many to many relationship

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148723/discussion-between-bikash-bilz-and-jagguy).

Comment: I have updated the code again, can you please try. I hope this time it will work for you perfectly :)

Comment: No good sorry. I dont believe it can be done like this. error:You are required to select the "SubjectsStudents.student_id" field

Comment: @jagguy Do what the error message says, select the `student_id` field too. That's the foreign key, and it is required in order for the ORM to be able to stitch the data together that is being retrieved in multiple queries. Also check the `contain()` docs, it shows how limit fields, and there's also a big yellow warning that mentions the foreign key requirement.

Comment: there is no student_id field though? Shouldnt i use matching for belongstomany ? I dont know what to do

Comment: @jagguy There is, or at least the should be one on the join table (as indicated in the error message), just try it and add `SubjectsStudents.student_id` to the fields list. `matching()` is for filtering rows, not columns.